# Alternate Coins Implementation in this pool

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monero-wallet-cli

I'm curious to use this pool for 5 of different cryptonote based coins.
which includes:
XDN,
Bitsum,
Dero,
BCN,
Karbo

Please give some advice to put them in the pool,
I've successfully deployed this pool on the server for monero but need to know about alternate coins implementation and one more thing , if we can implement them in the pool so should we use all of them coins on parallel basis in a single pool.
Thanks

Comment: What pool software are you using?

Comment: Sinpaa\nodejs-pool

Answer (score 1):

Adding a new coin to the pool requires creating and implementing a new js file in `/lib/coins`, creating and implementing a new js file in `/lib/payment_systems` and referencing both these new files in the `coinConfig.json` file. If you just duplicate an existing coins files and edit appropriately, that's probably the easiest method. Note, you'll need to be running a daemon for any coin you add of course.

With regards to running multiple coins in a single pool, you can't with nodejs-pool.